# Does Unit testing protect your code from other developers mistakes?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit4, loose-coupling, nunit-3.0

I've been looking into the benefits of unit testing, and verifying code correctness and the added benefit that you'll naturally create loosely coupled code if you do it properly. In other words a unit is as small as one method - not bigger. These seem to be the big 2. I just would like to know if good unit testing will ring-fence code and protect its functionality from other developers code changes (assuming a failed unit test is a failed build). Also is there any other benefits I've overlooked?

Comment: Proper encapsulation will help prevent other developer mistakes. By limiting unplanned use of methods, modules or logic only to what you "let them use", then you're limiting errors from other developers. Unit testing does none of that. On the contrary, unit testing will often-times require you to open your code-base more than functionally necessary.

The only thing unit tests enforce is that your modules and methods keep working as expected folowwing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the other (overlooked) benefits of having a decent unit test coverage is the fact that it can actually encourage developers dipping their toes into a big solution/old legacy code, knowing they have a safety net that should provide instant feedback when the refactoring has gone awry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the majority of the time, unit testing will indeed prevent other developer's mistakes. However, this is not true all the time. Testpoints are a better bet for a more viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Depends whether or not other developers won't just delete your tests.

But seriously, if you correctly modularise your code and make the tests clear, usually people will think twice about changing it if it breaks the tests.

Unless they have a good reason to make the change - and then they will need to change the tests accordingly, to describe the new functionality.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Unit testing protect your code from other developers mistakes?

Not exactly.

A unit test isolates a specific piece of code (the "unit"), and calls it in both positive and negative ways, testing the output each time against expected results. This ensure that unit is robust and meets the expected requirements - *within the context of that unit*.

This doesn't stop other developers making mistakes before passing values to your code, or acting incorrectly on your returned value. The value passed in to your code can be valid but still wrong. For example your code might expect a positive integer between 0 and 100, but your code has no idea that a specific caller passing the value of 50 is incorrect - your code can only act upon what it receives, it has no other context around that value. In this case a unit test on that calling code might pick up the problem, but a unit test on your code won't.

> I just would like to know if good unit testing will ring-fence code and protect its functionality from other developers code changes

Unit tests don't ring fence anything. Assuming well written tests, they'll tell you if your code was changed and it no longer matches its original intent. They won't tell you if a caller is passing the wrong values at run time, but they will help you make sure your code behaves correctly if a wrong value is passed in.

In my experience, unit tests are only as good as the person writing the code. If that person is a poor coder or doesn't properly understand the requirements then the tests could be worthless. I've seen some truly awful unit tests in the past, consequently I always advise that they should be just one part of your testing approach, you shouldn't rely on them exclusively - they are simply part of a disciplined approach.